# Insert LOTS of values in using dbClient

Tags: c#, c++, .net, dbclient

Currently I'm trying to insert a lot of values in my new project, but I can't figure out how to do that exactly. My 'simplest' SQL query is as follows, and this function works like it should:

```
dbClient.setQuery("INSERT INTO `rooms` (`roomtype`, `caption`, `owner`, `description`,     `category`, `state`, `users_now`, `users_max`, `model_name`, `public_ccts`, `score`, `tags`, `icon_bg`, `icon_fg`, `icon_items`, `password`, `wallpaper`, `floor`, `landscape`, `allow_pets`, `allow_pets_eat`, `allow_walkthrough`, `allow_hidewall`, `wallthick`, `floorthick`, `achievement`, `group_id`, `game_id`, `mute_settings`, `ban_settings`, `kick_settings`) VALUES " +
"('private', 'VIP CADEAU: Penthouse', @username, 'Ontvang deze kamer GRATIS bij het lid worden van VIP (http://wonderhotel.nl/vip).', 11, 'open', 0, 25, 'model_i', '', 1, '', 1, 0, '', '', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '1', '0', '0', '0', -2, -2, 0, 0, 0, '0', '1', '1');");
dbClient.addParameter("username", Session.GetHabbo().Username);
dbClient.runQuery();
```

But now I would like to insert more than 1 value, with the following query:

```
INSERT INTO `rooms` (`roomtype`, `caption`, `owner`, `description`, `category`, `state`, `users_now`, `users_max`, `model_name`, `public_ccts`, `score`, `tags`, `icon_bg`, `icon_fg`, `icon_items`, `password`, `wallpaper`, `floor`, `landscape`, `allow_pets`, `allow_pets_eat`, `allow_walkthrough`, `allow_hidewall`, `wallthick`, `floorthick`, `achievement`, `group_id`, `game_id`, `mute_settings`, `ban_settings`, `kick_settings`) VALUES
('private', 'Penthouse', @username, 'Ontvang deze kamer GRATIS bij het lid worden van VIP (http://wonderhotel.nl/vip).', 11, 'open', 7, 25, 'model_i', '', 1, '', 1, 0, '', '', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '1', '0', '0', '0', -2, -2, 0, 0, 0, '0', '1', '1'),
('private', 'Penthouse', @username, 'Ontvang deze kamer GRATIS bij het lid worden van VIP (http://wonderhotel.nl/vip).', 11, 'open', 7, 25, 'model_i', '', 1, '', 1, 0, '', '', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '1', '0', '0', '0', -2, -2, 0, 0, 0, '0', '1', '1'),
('private', 'Penthouse', @username, 'Ontvang deze kamer GRATIS bij het lid worden van VIP (http://wonderhotel.nl/vip).', 11, 'open', 7, 25, 'model_i', '', 1, '', 1, 0, '', '', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '1', '0', '0', '0', -2, -2, 0, 0, 0, '0', '1', '1'),
('private', 'Penthouse', @username, 'Ontvang deze kamer GRATIS bij het lid worden van VIP (http://wonderhotel.nl/vip).', 11, 'open', 7, 25, 'model_i', '', 1, '', 1, 0, '', '', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '1', '0', '0', '0', -2, -2, 0, 0, 0, '0', '1', '1'),
('private', 'Penthouse', @username, 'Ontvang deze kamer GRATIS bij het lid worden van VIP (http://wonderhotel.nl/vip).', 11, 'open', 7, 25, 'model_i', '', 1, '', 1, 0, '', '', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '1', '0', '0', '0', -2, -2, 0, 0, 0, '0', '1', '1'),
```

And thousands of other rows that follow after this...

But I have absolutely no idea how to run adapt my code (`dbClient`) to make it work.... A logical but messy solution could be:

```
dbClient.setQuery("INSERT INTO `rooms` (`roomtype`, `caption`, `owner`, `description`,     `category`, `state`, `users_now`, `users_max`, `model_name`, `public_ccts`, `score`, `tags`, `icon_bg`, `icon_fg`, `icon_items`, `password`, `wallpaper`, `floor`, `landscape`, `allow_pets`, `allow_pets_eat`, `allow_walkthrough`, `allow_hidewall`, `wallthick`, `floorthick`, `achievement`, `group_id`, `game_id`, `mute_settings`, `ban_settings`, `kick_settings`) VALUES " +
    "('private', 'VIP CADEAU: Penthouse', @username, 'Ontvang deze kamer GRATIS bij het lid worden van VIP (http://wonderhotel.nl/vip).', 11, 'open', 0, 25, 'model_i', '', 1, '', 1, 0, '', '', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '1', '0', '0', '0', -2, -2, 0, 0, 0, '0', '1', '1');");
dbClient.setQuery("INSERT INTO `rooms` (`roomtype`, `caption`, `owner`, `description`,     `category`, `state`, `users_now`, `users_max`, `model_name`, `public_ccts`, `score`, `tags`, `icon_bg`, `icon_fg`, `icon_items`, `password`, `wallpaper`, `floor`, `landscape`, `allow_pets`, `allow_pets_eat`, `allow_walkthrough`, `allow_hidewall`, `wallthick`, `floorthick`, `achievement`, `group_id`, `game_id`, `mute_settings`, `ban_settings`, `kick_settings`) VALUES " +
    "('private', 'VIP CADEAU: Penthouse', @username, 'Ontvang deze kamer GRATIS bij het lid worden van VIP (http://wonderhotel.nl/vip).', 11, 'open', 0, 25, 'model_i', '', 1, '', 1, 0, '', '', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '1', '0', '0', '0', -2, -2, 0, 0, 0, '0', '1', '1');");
```

But I don't want to repeat the 'INSERT INTO' over a 1000 times in my code..

Comment: What is "dbclient"?  What namespace is it from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Options:

- loop, using the simple code lots of times with different parameters
- use a tool that can do that for you (dapper has some close-to-basic tricks there, and most ORMs will allow simple list-based inserts)
- for very large inserts, "bulk copy" if your provider supports it - perhaps using FastMember to turn a list into an `IDataReader`

Comment: Thank you Marc. I'm going to try it with bulk copy.

Answer (score 1):

You just need multiple `INSERT` statements:

```
INSERT INTO `rooms` (`roomtype`, `caption`, `owner`, `description`, `category`, `state`, `users_now`, `users_max`, `model_name`, `public_ccts`, `score`, `tags`, `icon_bg`, `icon_fg`, `icon_items`, `password`, `wallpaper`, `floor`, `landscape`, `allow_pets`, `allow_pets_eat`, `allow_walkthrough`, `allow_hidewall`, `wallthick`, `floorthick`, `achievement`, `group_id`, `game_id`, `mute_settings`, `ban_settings`, `kick_settings`) VALUES
('private', 'Penthouse', @username, 'Ontvang deze kamer GRATIS bij het lid worden van VIP (http://wonderhotel.nl/vip).', 11, 'open', 7, 25, 'model_i', '', 1, '', 1, 0, '', '', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '1', '0', '0', '0', -2, -2, 0, 0, 0, '0', '1', '1');

INSERT INTO `rooms` (`roomtype`, `caption`, `owner`, `description`, `category`, `state`, `users_now`, `users_max`, `model_name`, `public_ccts`, `score`, `tags`, `icon_bg`, `icon_fg`, `icon_items`, `password`, `wallpaper`, `floor`, `landscape`, `allow_pets`, `allow_pets_eat`, `allow_walkthrough`, `allow_hidewall`, `wallthick`, `floorthick`, `achievement`, `group_id`, `game_id`, `mute_settings`, `ban_settings`, `kick_settings`) VALUES
('private', 'Penthouse', @username, 'Ontvang deze kamer GRATIS bij het lid worden van VIP (http://wonderhotel.nl/vip).', 11, 'open', 7, 25, 'model_i', '', 1, '', 1, 0, '', '', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '1', '0', '0', '0', -2, -2, 0, 0, 0, '0', '1', '1');
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment Chris! This could work, but there should be an easier solution than this, right? Imagine having 1000+ rows that need to be inserted and repeating the same code over and over again.

Comment: This is the standard way to do it in SQL (unfortunately). If you are looking for a speedy way, then various bulk copy methods (as @MarkGravell mentioned in his answer) exist to help with this.

Comment: I managed to fix it by using the bulk copy method, but now I'm stuck with another problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22591959/assign-variable-to-newly-generated-id