# Assign variable to newly generated ID

Tags: c#, dbclient

I'm running this query in my new project:

```
dbClient.setQuery("INSERT INTO `rooms` (`roomtype`, `caption`, `owner`, `description`, `category`, `state`, `users_now`, `users_max`, `model_name`, `public_ccts`, `score`, `tags`, `icon_bg`, `icon_fg`, `icon_items`, `password`, `wallpaper`, `floor`, `landscape`, `allow_pets`, `allow_pets_eat`, `allow_walkthrough`, `allow_hidewall`, `wallthick`, `floorthick`, `achievement`, `group_id`, `game_id`, `mute_settings`, `ban_settings`, `kick_settings`) VALUES " +
                                    "('private', 'VIP CADEAU: Penthouse', @username, 'Ontvang deze kamer GRATIS bij het lid worden van VIP (http://wonderhotel.nl/vip).', 11, 'open', 0, 25, 'model_i', '', 1, '', 1, 0, '', '', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '1', '0', '0', '0', -2, -2, 0, 0, 0, '0', '1', '1');");
                                    dbClient.addParameter("username", Session.GetHabbo().Username);
                                    dbClient.runQuery();
```

But now, I want to get the newly generated 'id' (=`NULL`) from this query and assign a parameter to it to use it in the following query as `@newid`:

```
dbClient.setQuery("INSERT INTO `items` (`user_id`, `room_id`, `base_item`, `extra_data`, `x`, `y`, `z`, `rot`, `wall_pos`, `rareid`) VALUES " +
"(@id, @newid, 99036, '0', 6, 6, 0.0002, 0, '', 0);");
                                    dbClient.addParameter("id", Session.GetHabbo().Id);
                                    dbClient.runQuery();
```

How can I assign the value generated in the first query to @newid? This solution looks logical to me, but it doesn't work:

```
dbClient.addParameter("roomid", dbClient.setQuery("LAST_INSERT_ID();");
```

Error: http://puu.sh/7GmCI/f5b6794d02.png

Thanks for the help!

@Tewr

```
dbClient.setQuery("INSERT INTO `rooms` (`id`, `roomtype`, `caption`, `owner`, `description`, `category`, `state`, `users_now`, `users_max`, `model_name`, `public_ccts`, `score`, `tags`, `icon_bg`, `icon_fg`, `icon_items`, `password`, `wallpaper`, `floor`, `landscape`, `allow_pets`, `allow_pets_eat`, `allow_walkthrough`, `allow_hidewall`, `wallthick`, `floorthick`, `achievement`, `group_id`, `game_id`, `mute_settings`, `ban_settings`, `kick_settings`) VALUES " +
                                    "(NULL, 'private', 'VIP CADEAU: Penthouse', @username, 'Ontvang deze kamer GRATIS bij het lid worden van VIP (http://wonderhotel.nl/vip).', 11, 'open', 0, 25, 'model_i', '', 1, '', 1, 0, '', '', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '1', '0', '0', '0', -2, -2, 0, 0, 0, '0', '1', '1');");
                                    dbClient.addParameter("username", Session.GetHabbo().Username);
                                    dbClient.setQuery("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();");
                        dbClient.runQuery();
dbClient.addParameter("roomid", dbClient.getRow()[0].ToString());
```

After that, the following code follows and uses the @roomid that we've defined previously.

```
  dbClient.setQuery("INSERT INTO `items` (`user_id`, `room_id`, `base_item`, `extra_data`, `x`, `y`, `z`, `rot`, `wall_pos`, `rareid`) VALUES " +
"(@id, @roomid, 99036, '0', 6, 6, 0.0002, 0, '', 0);");
                                    dbClient.addParameter("id", Session.GetHabbo().Id);
                                    dbClient.runQuery();
```

But this results in an error saying that @roomid isn't defined.

Comment: No one will help if you are not precise. What does it mean "it doesn't work"?

Comment: Well, because first of all it throws 3 errors at me (http://puu.sh/7GmCI/f5b6794d02.png) and the solution can't be that simple, I guess. I have no idea how to fix those 3 problems.

Comment: If you haven't tried Entity Framework http://entityframework.codeplex.com/, give it a try. Just a thought. Maybe you are looking performance that EF can't archive. In that case take a look at Dapper http://www.dapper.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your compilation errors and your existing code gave some clues:

This line does not compile since you are missing a parenthesis at the end, and setQuery() does not return a value:

```
dbClient.addParameter("roomid", dbClient.setQuery("LAST_INSERT_ID();");
```

So replace that with:

```
dbClient.setQuery("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();")
dbClient.runQuery();
dbClient.addParameter("roomid", dbClient.getRow()[0].ToString());
```

Now that this line in your code is compiling, it's not a guarantee that it will work... It looks like your code should have already worked in the first place. Make sure your table is configured correctly with [AUTO_INCREMENT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html).